# (openpyxl) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

```py
from os import listdir
from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook

files = listdir(r'C:\Users\MyID\Desktop\auto_task\examples\06')
result_xlsx = Workbook()
result_sheet =result_xlsx.active

for file in files:
    if file[-4:] != 'xlsx':
        continue

    tg_xlsx = load_workbook(file, read_only=True)
    tg_sheet = tg_xlsx.active

    for row in tg_sheet.iter_rows():
        row_data = []
        for cell in row:
            row_data.append(cell.value)
        result_sheet.append(row_data)

result_xlsx.save('result.xlsx')
```

I've been practicing openpyxl module by reading a book and there's error.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '2017.12.1.xlsx'
```

As you see, I wrote the specific path in `files = listdir....`
and also I have a excel file that name `2017.12.1.xlsx`

what's the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give full path to the file --> `load_workbook(os.path.join(path, file), read_only=True)`

**Ex:**

```
path = r'C:\Users\MyID\Desktop\auto_task\examples\06'
files = listdir(path)
result_xlsx = Workbook()
result_sheet =result_xlsx.active

for file in files:
    if file[-4:] != 'xlsx':
        continue

    tg_xlsx = load_workbook(os.path.join(path, file), read_only=True)
    tg_sheet = tg_xlsx.active

    for row in tg_sheet.iter_rows():
        row_data = []
        for cell in row:
            row_data.append(cell.value)
        result_sheet.append(row_data)

result_xlsx.save('result.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thanks for answering and I solved the problem.
but I don't understand exactly. 


'files' = r'C:\Users\MyID\Desktop\auto_task\examples\06'
so 'file' has same path right? 
so what's difference between without adding 'os.path.join~~' ?

Comment: `os.listdir` will only return the file names. try `print(os.listdir(path))`

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much. here's my last question. 
In 'result_xlsx.save()', do you know how to change the path?
I tried result_xlsx.save(path,'result.xlsx') but it didn't work .

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in a full day for the same error.I tried in spyder, Idle,moved xl file here and there,  still i couldn't able to find it ..But later i found that i created the file name itself 'example.xlsx' instead of 'example' alone. That's the reason the the error file not found killed me..what a silly blunder....