# How can I set protection on all excel files in a directory with openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I thought I would be able to set protection on the first sheet of all excel files in a directory using the method below, but for some reason I keep getting a `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:` error even though the file exists and is found.

The reason I believe that it should work is that I utilized a `print` statement to print the file name and it works followed by the error that I added below my code.  You can even see that it finds and prints "test2.xlsx" but then claims the file doesn't exist. The python file IS in the same directory as the folder so this can't be a path issue right?

```
import openpyxl
import os

folder = "my_folder"

for file in os.listdir(folder):
    if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
        print(file)
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
        ws = wb.worksheets[0]
        ws.protection.sheet = True
        ws.protection.password = "password"
        wb.save(file)
```

the traceback is:
test2.xlsx <- this is the result of the print statement.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rory Moore\Desktop\test_excel\lock.py", line 9, in <module>
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
  File "C:\Users\Rory Moore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 315, in load_workbook
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
  File "C:\Users\Rory Moore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
  File "C:\Users\Rory Moore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 96, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
  File "C:\Users\Rory Moore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\zipfile.py", line 1239, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test2.xlsx'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Openpyxl will need the folder name included in the filepath if the python file is in a different directory than the xlsx file. Is this your folder structure?

```
/code.py
/my_folder/file.xlsx
/my_folder/file2.xlsx
```

If so, then this should work:

```
import openpyxl
import os

folder = "my_folder"

for file in os.listdir(folder):
    if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
        print(file)
        filePath = f"{folder}/{file}"
        print(filePath)
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filePath)
        ws = wb.worksheets[0]
        ws.protection.sheet = True
        ws.protection.password = "password"
        wb.save(filePath)
```

Another example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55918587/openpyxl-filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: That is not true when the python file is in the same directory as the folder, furthermore the print statement confirms that it found the file as I stated in my question. FWIW I tried the full path prior to this attempt and got the same result.

Comment: Ah I'll make an edit to make it a bit more clear. I think you just need to add the "my_folder" part while also using the full path. I was able to reproduce the error and fix it on my end.

Comment: Can you show your folder structure for clarity?

Comment: So yes I did use part of your answer to solve it. But `wb.save(file)` had to be `wb.save(fullpath)` and also one variable for the path is sufficient like so `path = r"C:\Users\Rory Moore\Desktop\test_excel\my_folder"` and then fullpath can be `full_path = f"{path}/{file}"`. Then it worked, if you  update your answer as such ill accept it since it did solve my issue by clarifying the path error.